# C++ pthreads multi-tasking [windows]

Tags: c++, windows, pthreads

For a solution to an earlier problem, I was kindly pointed to multi-threading (via pthreads).

The original problem is thus:
I have two functions, one of which is the main body, which is real-time; the other is a continually running function that blocks. The real-time, when attempting to run the blocking function, obvious blocks, making it unresponsive to the user which is unacceptable as a real-time process.

The original aim was to make the blocking function independent of the real-time solution (or at least, pseudo-independent), which I attempted with pthreads.

Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
void * RenderImages(void * Data)
{
    while(1); //Simulating a permanently blocking process
    return NULL;
}

int main(int ArgC, char *ArgVar[])
{
    pthread_t threads[PTHREAD_NUMBER];


    void *Ptr = NULL;

    int I = 0;
    I = pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, RenderImages, Ptr);
    if(I != 0)
    {
        printf("pthread_create Error!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    I = pthread_join(threads[0],NULL);

    //Doesn't reach here as pthread_join is blocking

    printf("Testing!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The code above, however, blocks on calling pthread_join (which makes pthread nothing more than an unnecessarily complicated way of calling the function directly - which defeats the point).

**My question is thus:**

What functions would I have to use, to make it so I can run a pthread for a few milliseconds, suspend the process, then run another function, then go back and run the process for a few more milli-seconds etc?

OR

If the above isn't possible, what solution is there to the original problem?

Comment: It blocks because neither of your threads does anything. The idea is that both will be running at once, both doing useful work. As it stands your main thread blocks on join, but the other thread is actually running. You now need to do some real work in the main thread (like a loop of some sort), before the join.

Comment: It would be doing work (however, to keep the code simplified, an infinite loop would actually emulate the function call). Because it's calling an already defined class function that blocks for the entire duration it runs. In a sense, what I want is what processors already do in terms of running one process, suspending it, running another, suspending that, then running the original process.

Comment: @SightS2 Which is exactly what threads do! I really don't see your problem. The OS is currently swapping between your threads, until the main thread blocks on join, at which point only the second thread is active, but you can't see it because they don't do anything!

Comment: @unapersson I am not entirely sure what you mean. How do I swap between threads? I am completely unfamiliar with pthreads.

Comment: @SightS2 You don't swap between threads - the OS does it for you, just like it would swap between processes on Linux. Modify your code so the RenderImages print "A" in an infinite loop, and the main function prints "B" in an infinite loop (before the join) to see this.

Comment: @unapersson I wish there was some way I could thank you. You have solved the problem... Oh wow. Awesome!

Comment: @SightS2 Think nothing of it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the "main" thread only cares when the "blocking" thread has completed its work, I think you want condition variables. Look into `pthread_cond_wait` and `pthread_cond_signal`.

Answer (score 0):

pthread_join is the function you use to wait for a thread to end.

http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html

Use pthread_sigmask to manage suspend states:

http://man.yolinux.com/cgi-bin/man2html?cgi_command=pthread_sigmask

Answer (score 0):

You can always use 3 threads, one for each function plus the main thread.

Comment: Not sure if that would enable me to switch between a real-time and a blocking thread?

Comment: If you block the realtime thread, then the blocking thread can run and vice versa. To block and unblock thread conditionally, you can use what Mark B suggest.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a queuing mechanism. Your main thread will create 'Jobs'. You then place these 'Jobs' onto your backlog queue where your Worker Thread will pick them up and process then. When the job is done. The worker thread places the now completed 'Jobs' onto the completed queue. You main thread can intermittently check the completed queue and if there is a completed job,it will pick up the 'Job' and do whatever it needs to with it. Your worker thread then goes into a wait state until the next job comes along.

There are numerous ways to roll out the queues. The queue can be a unix pipe. A windows [IO Completion Port](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or you can roll out your own with a linked list/arrays, conditional variables and mutexes.